# compilation error in vc++ vs2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-c++

I am getting an error while compiling in vc++ vs2005.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16
referenced in function "void __cdecl MsgBox(char const *,char const *,...)"
(?MsgBox@@YAXPBD0ZZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think their is conflict between nsvcrt and mfc80u.lib

Comment: If you want to add to your question then edit it - do NOT post additions as answers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few causes of linker errors:

- Missing references
- If you're using external headers or source files ensure they are all referenced

Could you post a code snippet of the area in question?